# How can I convert JsValue to Array[Int] in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala.js, play-json

I am using the Play Json Library to parse json in scala and I have a value that looks like this

```
scala> val extract = (payload \ "id")
extract: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [8,18]
```

I want to convert JsValue to Array[Int].

Answer (score 2):

Well, because, you are working with parsing json - which implies that along with that you need to validate it and properly handle errors, it not so easy just convert it - Play JSON will force you to handle errors.
So, answering your question there you can try something like described below:

```
   val jsonString = "{\"id\": [1, 2, 3] }"
    val payload = Json.parse(jsonString)
    // This will return `JsResult` - success or failure, which need to be properly handled
    println((payload \ "id").validate[Array[Int]].map(_.toList))

    // This is unsafe operation and might throw exception for un-expected JSON
    println((payload \ "id").validate[Array[Int]].get.toList)
```

which prints out for me next:

```
JsSuccess(List(1, 2, 3),)
List(1, 2, 3)
```

I added `toList` just for output readability. Hope this will help you!

Comment: Why call `.asInstanceOf[JsObject]`?

Comment: @MarioGalic this was made for sake of simplicity in this example - `JsValue` is base class describing all the possible json types: primitives, arrays, objects, null etc. In production code it should not be like this off course. Do you thing it is better to refactor this code in another way?

Comment: Seems to work without `asInstanceOf`, for example, `Json.parse("""{ "id": [8, 18] }""").\("id").validate[List[Int]]`

Comment: @MarioGalic Oh, Thank you very much for suggestion - for some reason I thought that this method exists only in `JsObject`, I'll remove it then. Thank you again for a help!